How do I manually backfeed a ZPL printer?
I have printed an RFID tag on my Zebra ZT411 printer, and I want to manually backfeed it so I can read it.
What ZPL command(s) will do that?  I have been looking and I cannot find a simple "backfeed" command.  Plenty of commands to set up auto-backfeed for cutoff or other post-print handling, but nothing that lets me manually roll the label back so it is placed under the RFID head so I can then read the data off the tag.
Can anyone help?
